# get current connection in flask socket.io

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io

I want to make multiple emitting to an individual socket connection using flask's socket.io extension.

```
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room


# creating flask app and io...

@io.on("/saySomething")
def saying():
  emit("said", "hello")
  saying2()

def saying2():
  # ...
  # doing something long and important
  # ...
  emit("said", "and how are you?")
```

I do not know which connection saying2 is emitting to. Should I pass current connection to saying2 method? How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `saying2()` is emitting to the client that sent the `/saySomething` event. This is based on a concept similar to request contexts in standard Flask.

The emit function has two optional arguments to send to other clients:

- `broadcast=True` will send to all connected clients, including the client that sent the `/saySomething` event.
- `room=<room-name>` will send to all clients attached to the given room. If you want to address individual clients, then put each client in a different room and target the desired room.